# Rails 7 respond_to ActionController::UnknownFormat error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I've been playing around with Ruby on Rails 7 and I want to update a div element rendering a partial with `format.js` but an error arise when the execution reaches this line.

This is my controller:

```
class StocksController < ApplicationController
  def search
    if params[:stock].present?
      @stock = Stock.new_lookup(params[:stock])

      if @stock
        respond_to do |format| # <-------------------- Here is the error
          format.js { render partial: 'users/result' }
        end
      else
        flash[:alert] = 'Please enter a valid symbol to search'
        redirect_to my_portfolio_path
      end
    else
      flash[:alert] = 'Please enter a symbol to search'
      redirect_to my_portfolio_path
    end
  end
end
```

I created a view where I created a div to modify only that div which id is 'results'.

```
  <%= form_tag search_stock_path, remote: true, method: :get do %>
    <div class='form-group row'>
      <div class='col-sm-9 pe-0'>
        <%= text_field_tag :stock, 
          params[:stock], 
          placeholder: 'Stock ticker', 
          autofocus: true, 
          class: 'form-control form-control-lg' %>
      </div>
      <div class='col-sm-3 ps-0'>
        <%= button_tag type: :submit, class: 'btn btn-success' do %>
          <i class='fa fa-search fa-2x'></i>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div id='results'> <!-- This is the div -->
</div>
```

I have a partial name `users/result.js.erb` and when I submit the search I receive this error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat - ActionController::UnknownFormat:
  app/controllers/stocks_controller.rb:7:in `search'
```

This is my directory for more details:

[image: rails_directory]

And this is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root "welcome#index"
  get 'my_portfolio', to: 'users#my_portfolio'
  get 'search_stock', to: 'stocks#search'
end
```

Anyone knows what's going on here when `respond_to` is executed?

Why this `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error?

Comment: You're getting the exception because you're most likely not sending a request for `application/javascript` when you click the form. This can be verfied by checking the Rails logs and looking at the network tab in the web inspector in your browser. This happens because the Rails UJS handler which "AJAXifies" normal form submissions isn't working in your application. This can be because you haven't included the asset or a script error in your JS which is preventing it from working.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? - I have the same where in Rails 6 it works fine but in Rails 7 it shows ActionController::UnknownFormat

Comment: Hi @Hackeron. No, I haven't. However I think this is something you address with Turbo Frames and Turbo Streams. I haven't tried yet.